# MySQL use DISTINCT in GROUP_CONTACT on a different column than the output one

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to use GROUP_CONCAT with DISTINCT, but by executing the distinction on a different column.
For example, I'm doing this:

```
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT tags.tag SEPARATOR ' ') as tags"
```

But a tag could be the same characters with a different id, so I would need to do something like this:

```
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT(tags.tag_id) tags.tag SEPARATOR ' ') as tags"
```

However I can't find anything about this, any ideas?

**SIMPLIFIED table data examples (model and SQL request are a lot more complex with multiple joins and tables):**
*items* table:
*item_id*, *title*, ...
1, Smith, ...
2, Bob, ...
...

*tags* table:
*tag_id*, *tag*, *item_id*, ...
1, Montreal, 1, ...
2, Toronto, 1, ...
3, Toronto, 1, ...
4, New-York, 2, ...
...

**The MySQL query:**

```
...
SELECT items.item_id, items.title,
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT tags.tag_id SEPARATOR ',') as tag_ids",
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT tags.tag SEPARATOR ' ') as tags"
LEFT JOIN tags ON items.item_id = tags.item_id
GROUP BY items.item_id
..
```

Expected result:
item1.title = "Smith"
item1.tag_ids = "1 2 3"
item1.tags = "Montreal Toronto Toronto"
...

Actual result:
item1.title = "Smith"
item1.tag_ids = "1 2 3"
item1.tags = "Montreal Toronto" <-- MISMATCH IN TAGS COUNT BECAUSE OF DISTINCT
...

**NOTE:**
I would like to avoid sub-queries like

```
SELECT WHERE tags.item_id IN(SELECT ...)
```

Comment: Nice context description, but not sure what is the question. Show us sample data and expected output. 
 Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

Comment: You really need to show some data and expected output. I am having a hard time to understand your issue.

Comment: I changed my question, removed all explanations and put only data with expected result and actual result

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure what you want but if I'm right, you want distinct tag_ids and then corresponding tag names, so 'montreal toronto toronto' would be fine for you:

```
SELECT item_id,
       GROUP_CONCAT(tag_id SEPARATOR ' ') AS tag_ids,
       GROUP_CONCAT(tag SEPARATOR ' ') AS tags
FROM
    (SELECT items.item_id AS item_id,
            tags.tag_id AS tag_id,
            tags.tag AS tag
     FROM items
     JOIN tags ON tags.item_id = items.item_id
     GROUP BY 1,
              2) AS distinct_groups
GROUP BY item_id
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for offering an idea Jan! I re-wrote my question completely to help you guys understand. What you wrote there seemed like it would be working but I'd like to avoid sub-queries like that since our framework makes sub-queries janky.